# How do I run psalm in my local dev environment?

Tags: php, lint

My builds are failing in Travis because of psalm! How can I find out about these errors before pushing up my changes?

Answer (score 1):

From your working directory in terminal type:

```
./vendor/bin/psalm --show-info=false | grep <path to your file>
```

e.g. from within /Web-Expensify type:

```
./vendor/bin/psalm --show-info=false | grep lib/Account.php
```

Give it a second and you should see the psalm errors related to the file you are trying to fix.